# Javascript innerHTML: Button not working inside Table

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I added a button inside my innerHTML table, the button on the first row work, but those follow is not working.

HTML:

```
<p id="stat_tbl"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
let tbl = document.getElementById("stat_tbl")

var txt = ""
txt += "<table>"
txt += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Code</th></tr>"
for(x in obj) {
    txt += "<tr><td> + obj[x].name + </td>"
    txt += "<td><button type='' id='btnclick' onclick='tes()' value='" + obj[x].code + "'>Show Code</button></td></tr>"
}
txt += "</table>"

tbl.innerHTML = txt
```

I tried:

```
let btn = document.createElement("button")

txt += "<td>" + btn + "</td></tr>"

tbl.appendChild(btn)
```

but the Output is = [object HTMLButtonElement]

Comment: In the first snippet the line `txt += "<tr><td> + obj[x].name + </td>"` includes `obj[x]` to the string literally, i.e. it is missing a pair of quotes. When adding the quotes, the snippet [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/vgcjo0p5/) ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some way to resolve this problem in you code.

Bases on, not very efficient, but works, approach where `onclick` handler are set inline you may pass the `event` to handle click. And then take reference to button via `event.target`.

Avoid set the same `id` for numbers of elements like `id='btnclick'`, there is no sense.

```js
let tbl = document.getElementById("stat_tbl")
let obj = {a: {name: 'aObj', code: 'A'}, b: {name: 'bObj', code: 'B'}};
var txt = ""
txt += "<table>"
txt += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Code</th></tr>"
for(x in obj) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" + obj[x].name + "</td>"
    txt += "<td><button type='' onclick='tes(event)' value='" + obj[x].code + "'>Show Code</button></td></tr>"
}
txt += "</table>"

tbl.innerHTML = txt

function tes(ev) {
 console.info(ev.target.value);
}
```

```html
<p id="stat_tbl"></p>
```

Comment: Also add thead/tbody and not recommended to have inline event handlers

Comment: And why not tes(this) ?

Comment: @mplungjan, I'm prefer to not loose the event. If that is not requirement `this` also may used. Really, why not.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to delegate like I do in [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380718/295783) - there you get the best of all worlds. The event and the button in an unobtrusive manner

Comment: I should agree, event delegation in almost (not all, almost) cases are better, that true.  But, sorry, I may suggest it's not related to this question.

Comment: I do not believe in just answering the question. If the premise is wrong, then answering a syntax question is not teaching OP anything

Comment: Clearly, I can say that I also share your point of view. May say, IMHO, it is better to learn something step by step. I think it can be a slightly complicated to understand the answer to a question you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop like this, it's work for me.

```
for(let x in obj) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" + obj[x].name + "</td>"
    txt += "<td><button type='' id='btnclick' onclick='tes()' value='" + obj[x].code + "'>Show Code</button></td></tr>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A button without any type (either button or submit) works like a submit button. As there is no form, nothing will be submitted.

You may use the attributes of the other button for yours.

```js
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.type = 'button';
btn.onclick = tes; // the function tes() must be declared
btn.value = 'Click me';

// Better use DOM here
// txt += "<td>" + btn + "</td></tr>";

let td = document.createElement('td');
td.appendChild(btn);

let tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.appendChild(td);

tbl.appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create valid html
2. delegate the button click

```js
const obj = {a: {name: 'aObj', code: 'A'}, b: {name: 'bObj', code: 'B'}};
const tbl = document.getElementById("stat_tbl")
var txt = []
txt.push("<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Code</th></tr></thead><tbody>");
for (x in obj) {
  txt.push("<tr><td>" + obj[x].name + "</td>");
  txt.push("<td><button type='button' class='show' value='" + obj[x].code + "'>Show Code</button></td></tr>");
}
txt.push("</tbody></table>");

tbl.innerHTML = txt.join("");

tbl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("show")) {
    console.log(tgt.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="stat_tbl"></p>
```

Using template literals

```js
const obj = {a: {name: 'aObj', code: 'A'}, b: {name: 'bObj', code: 'B'}};
const tbl = document.getElementById("stat_tbl")
var txt = []
txt.push(`<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Code</th></tr></thead><tbody>`);
for (x in obj) {
  txt.push(`<tr><td>${obj[x].name}</td>`);
  txt.push(`<td><button type='button' class='show' value='${obj[x].code}'>Show Code</button></td></tr>`);
}
txt.push(`</tbody></table>`);

tbl.innerHTML = txt.join("");

tbl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("show")) {
    console.log(tgt.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="stat_tbl"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example you have a button to be created and its ID is ***buttonID*** and on click on the button a ***function1*** has to be called.

If
you are creating the JavaScript function on loading the page later on creating the button, the function will not work.

if
you are creating the javascript ***function1*** after loading the button, it works.

I have just tried and is working.